# How to get on video Shell folder with command line for any windows system?

Tags: batch-file, vlc

I'm making a new batch file to convert any ***.mp4 files to *.mp3 files** with **VLC** in command line, but i want to improve it to choose the Input folder on Videos for any windows system !

My question is : **How to get on videos folder with command line for any windows system?**

Here is my code : ***MP4-MP3_Converter.bat***

```bat
@echo off
Title Convert (*.mp4) to (*.mp3) with VLC by (c) Hackoo 2017
mode con:cols=85 lines=5 & COLOR 0E
Taskkill /IM "vlc.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
echo.
set "VLC_URL=http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html"

IF /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (
        Set "vlc=%ProgramFiles%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
    ) else (
        Set "vlc=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
)

If Not Exist "%vlc%" (
    Cls & COLOR 0C
    echo.
    Echo       "The VLC program is not installed on your system"
    TimeOut /T 5 /NoBreak>nul
    Start "" %VLC_URL%
    Exit
)

Set "MP4Folder=C:\MP4Folder"
Set "MP3Folder=C:\MP3Folder"
If not exist "%MP3Folder%" MD "%MP3Folder%"
CD /D "%MP4Folder%"
for %%a in (*.mp4) do (
    Cls
    echo(
    echo           Please wait a while ... The Conversion is in progress ...
    echo   Conversion of "%%~na.mp4" to "%%~na.mp3"
    "%vlc%" -I dummy "%%a" --sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=128,vcodec=dummy}:std{access="file",mux="raw",dst="%MP3Folder%\%%~na.mp3"} vlc://quit
)
Explorer "%MP3Folder%" & Exit
```

Comment: Why don't you `set /p` a location, and in the `for` loop, use `(%variable%\*.mp4)`? I don't understand this code well enough so I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes you are wrong ! and with your downvote too ?? i don't want to let the user choose the folder , just i want to search where the videos shell folder is located just all !

Comment: are you sure VLC will be in `%ProgramFiles%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe`? I always use the portable VLC and put it in my own folder. Moreover I'll use 64-bit version on 64-bit Windows instead of 32-bit one

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc I have tested it on Windows 7 (64 bits) and it worked for me !

Comment: @Hackoo the fact that it works on your system doesn't mean that it'll work everywhere. Not everyone installs to the default folder, and not everyone uses the installed version, esp. in the past when no installers were available

Comment: @Hackoo I didn't downvote you.

Comment: It's unclear to what range of windows versions you do refer. The specialfolder `MyVideos` wasn't defined from start but added later on (as well as `CommonVideos`).  The easiest way to obtain it is in PowerShell: `[Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyVideos")` but PoSh v2.0 doesn't enumerate `MyVideos`

Comment: @LotPings i think you put me on the right direction, so we could hack it to get it working in batch, as there are some registry keys that contain this information. we can find them in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` *"My Video"* would be the needed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how consistent this is across different Windows versions, but I suspect you can use `"%userprofile%\videos"`.

But what is so special about that location? You are making a big assumption that all videos of interest are in that location. For example, I never use that folder, yet I have loads of videos on my hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i think i will accept your answer as well !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @LotPings,that put me on the right direction !

So we could hack it to get it working in batch, as there are some registry keys that contain this information. we can find them in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` *"My Video"* would be the needed value.

So with this batch file we can do it :

```bat
@echo off
Set "ShellFolderKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
Set "MyKey=My Video"
@For /f "tokens=4,* Delims= " %%A in ('Reg Query "%ShellFolderKey%" /v "%MyKey%" ^| Findstr /C:"%MyKey%"') Do (
    Set "MyVideoShellFolder=%%A"
)
echo "%MyVideoShellFolder%"
pause
```